# How to implement Unity Container DI in Azure Function v2

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

Earlier in WebAPI, I used to implement Unity container Dependency Injection as below

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //I want to implement below in Azure Function V2
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IFilterRepository, FilterRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<INEORepository, NEORepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container); 
    }
}
```

How can I implement above code in Azure Function V2.

I had gone through few online articles but didn't get proper solution.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: It's out of box now as service. have you checked official documentation ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Comment: Azure function is based on aspnet core so you can otherwise ue your own DI container or using the default integration

Comment: azure functions are meant to be small, discrete, pieces of functionality. injecting services into it is an antipattern, even though it gives you that ability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below code to implement DI in Azure functions.

```
  public class GenericDependencyInjection
    {
        private static readonly UnityContainer UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        public GenericDependencyInjection()
        {
            try
            {
                UnityContainer.RegisterType<IOperations,Operations>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ;
            }
        }

          public T Retrieve<T>()
        {
            return UnityContainer.Resolve<T>();
        }

        }
```

I have called Retrieve method by passing generic type as below in other classes

```
var data = new GenericDependencyInjection().Retrieve<EmpDetails>();
            return await data.UpdateDetails(EmpId, Name); //calling class EmpDetails method
```